# Mobile Viewport zoom back

Tags: javascript, zooming, viewport

I want to allow the user to zoom when he clicked on an image and I don't want to allow him to zoom if there is no image.

```
// image function 
viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes');

// no image function
viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
```

The problem:
If the user can zoom he can't go back to NORMAL disabled zoom because the no image function disables the zoom BUT the zoomfactor is not going back to the normal viewport.

So after the no image function it is possible to zoom but there is a zoom-factor already :/

Do you have any idea how to zoom back to the normal viewport in the no image function? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the viewport. There is a better way to achieve the same thing -> http://lab.hakim.se/zoom-js/

I'm sure that if you play with the viewport like that you will have problems in most of the mobile devices.

Comment: Ok, thx! But is there a possibility to allow the user to zoom instead of zoom automatically?

Comment: I'll suggest to disable the zooming and play with css transformations. you may even scale up the body, move it a bit and the effect will be the same.

Comment: I have no idea how to let the user zoom with two fingers and then zoom exactly this bit back.

Comment: But you said that you want to zoom the image when the user clicks on it. Not when he uses two fingers.

Comment: Sorry I think it was a misunderstanding. I said I want to allow the user to zoom, when he sees the images (image function) and if he doesn't it should be not allowed to zoom but the zoom should be 0.