# How can I zoom out after input is entered on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mobile, responsive-design

When a user focuses on a text input, mobile browsers zoom in for convenience. This is good.

But on a single page app, you don't refresh the page upon the form being submitted, so the viewport doesn't return to its non-zoomed state. This makes it difficult for the user to get their bearings again, or navigate as they did before. It is possible for them to double tap, to return the viewport to normal, but many of our users wouldn't know to do that.

I believe I am asking the same thing as the following questions, none of which provide a reliable answer. I would strongly prefer not to have to include another JS library.

[Mobile-friendly web design: How to programmatically zoom out after text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057256/mobile-friendly-web-design-how-to-programmatically-zoom-out-after-text-input)

[Mobile Viewport zoom back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696251/mobile-viewport-zoom-back)

Comment: could you add this to the form tag ? `onsubmit="document.body.style.zoom="100%"`. Might work.

Comment: It's going to take a bit of time to implement this within the app I'm working -- the submit handler is fairly complex.

Comment: Add it as a click on the submit button maybe, what about a onload on the results page ?

Comment: I have the same problem and tried to solve it with the zoom style. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I tested it on an iPhone XS in Safari. I think the zoom isn't done through css - at least there are not traces in the dev tools - so it might not be possible to solve the problem with css.